# FormsAppCompatActivity and MasterDetailPage: no Toolbar

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

**UPDATE**: Apparently this is intentional, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329260/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-for-masterdetailpage-to-use-the-toolbar).

---

**EDIT**: It turns out that the problem is that the Toolbar doesn't get added to the MasterDetailPage, but rather to the page I set as the Detail page (which is a NavigationPage in my case).

**So the problem now becomes: Why is there no Toolbar when I use a MasterDetailPage?**

---

I've upgraded to the new FormsAppCompatActivity. There are a lot of bugs, I'm going through them one by one.

Now, the drawer is being displayed over the Toolbar. I want the Toolbar to be always on top, so the drawer should be below it.

[image]

My RootView is a MasterDetailPage:

```
        RootView = new MasterDetailPage {
            Master = PageSubs,
            Detail = AppNavPage,
        };
```

Here is my style.xml:

```
    <style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbar_style">@style/LightToolbar</item>
```

ToolbarStyle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="LightToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
        <item name="android:background">#0087DC</item>
     </style>
    <style name="DarkToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
     </style>
    <style name="AMOLEDToolbar" parent="DarkToolbar">
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
     </style>
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the default behaviour that Google is enforcing now.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html